# SQL Server Advanced Denormalization

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to de-normalize data using T-SQL, I tried using unpivot function. But it returned output like this. I need a different output please suggest steps. Thank you.

```
product class   type    Value
----------------------------------
prod1   classA  AFD     2
prod1   classA  AFD_TS  6/29/2017
prod1   classA  CCD     5
prod1   classA  CCD_TS  7/4/2017
prod1   classA  MSD     8
prod1   classA  MSD_TS  7/9/2017
```

Query

```
select u.product, u.class,u.type, u.value
from source_table s
unpivot
(
  value
  for type in (AFD, AFD_TS, CCD, CCD_TS, MSD, MSD_TS)
) u;
```

Original input

```
product class   AFD AFD_TS      CCD CCD_TS      MSD MSD_TS
--------------------------------------------------------------
prod1   classA  2   6/29/2017   5   7/4/2017    8   7/9/2017
prod1   classB  3   6/30/2017   6   7/5/2017    9   7/10/2017
prod1   classC  4   7/1/2017    7   7/6/2017    1   7/11/2017
prod2   classA  12  7/2/2017    15  7/7/2017    18  7/12/2017
prod2   classB  13  7/3/2017    16  7/8/2017    19  7/13/2017
prod2   classC  14  7/4/2017    17  7/9/2017    11  7/14/2017
```

Expected output

```
product class   type Value TS
-----------------------------------
prod1   classA  AFD 2   6/29/2017
prod1   classA  CCD 5   7/4/2017
prod1   classA  MSD 8   7/9/2017
prod1   classB  AFD 3   6/30/2017
prod1   classB  CCD 6   7/5/2017
prod1   classB  MSD 9   7/10/2017
prod1   classC  AFD 4   7/1/2017
prod1   classC  CCD 7   7/6/2017
prod1   classC  MSD 1   7/11/2017
prod2   classA  AFD 12  7/2/2017
prod2   classA  CCD 15  7/7/2017
prod2   classA  MSD 18  7/12/2017
prod2   classB  AFD 13  7/3/2017
prod2   classB  CCD 16  7/8/2017
prod2   classB  MSD 19  7/13/2017
prod2   classC  AFD 14  7/4/2017
prod2   classC  CCD 17  7/9/2017
prod2   classC  MSD 11  7/14/2017
```

PS - Before down voting please state the reason for down voting. for you, this question maybe dumb, but I really tried a lot on this requirement.

```
Query for creating test data.

create table source_table(product varchar(20), class varchar(20), AFD varchar(20), AFD_TS varchar(20), CCD varchar(20), CCD_TS varchar(20), MSD varchar(20), MSD_TS varchar(20))

insert into source_table
values('prod1',   'classA',  2,   '6/29/2017',   5,   '7/4/2017' ,   8 ,  '7/9/2017'),
('prod1',   'classB',  3,   '6/30/2017',   6,   '7/5/2017',    9,   '7/10/2017'),
('prod1',   'classC',  4,   '7/1/2017',    7,   '7/6/2017',    1,   '7/11/2017'),
('prod2',   'classA',  12,  '7/2/2017',    15,  '7/7/2017',    18,  '7/12/2017'),
('prod2',   'classB',  13,  '7/3/2017',    16,  '7/8/2017',    19,  '7/13/2017'),
('prod2',   'classC',  14,  '7/4/2017',    17,  '7/9/2017',    11,  '7/14/2017')
```

Comment: Original output data is confusing.. How you got the original output? What is the first result set. Better to add just sample data and expected output along with the query you have tried so far

Comment: @Prdp updated with query

Comment: Still am not clear with the last schema setup given.. But anyway I think you need pivot not unpivot.. check here I have created demo http://rextester.com/QIEDW84523

Comment: @Prdp thank you. this is the result I am looking for. but I wanted to do it with pivot/unpivot functions as I thought group by query will take lot of time for processing. my source data has more than 10 million records. plz suggest if my assumption is right.

Comment: Technical `conditional Aggregate/Cross tab` will be bit faster than `Pivot` operator http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may help

**Example**

```
Select product
      ,class
      ,B.*
 From  source_table A
 Cross Apply ( values ('AFD',AFD,AFD_TS)
                     ,('CCD',CCD,CCD_TS)
                     ,('MSD',MSD,MSD_TS)
             ) B (type,value,ts)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: thank you. If you were in my organization, I would have got you a beer. :)

Comment: @Gokul  Thanks for the grin  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `Pivot` the data not `UnPivot`. Here is one way to do it using conditional Aggregate

```
select product,class,
       max(case when type not like '%/_TS' escape '/' then value end) as Value,
       max(case when type like '%/_TS' escape '/' then value end) as TS
from temp
group by product,class,left(type,3)
```

- **[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/QIEDW84523)**